# Map degree and coverings

Tags: algebraic-topology

If a continuous, surjective map between two compact and connected manifolds has degree larger than 0, this implies that the map is a covering?

Answer (score 1):

I guess "degree 0" means constant map. The answer is no.

For example, consider the map $\Bbb P^1 \to \Bbb P^1, z \mapsto z^2$. It's not a covering map because the cardinality of the preimage is not constant. On the other hand, if you ask that the map is differentiable and that the differential is surjective in every point it becomes true. A nice reference about these ideas is the book of Milnor about differential topology.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take any map of degree not equal to $\pm1$ in $S^2$. It can't be a covering map since the only possible covering maps $f:S^2 \to S^2$ are homeomorphisms (due to the fact that $S^2$ is simply-connected), and a non-$\pm1$ degree map on $S^2$ can't be a homeomorphism.

Comment: But in my case I have to demostrate that every map from a g-torus to an h-torus with g<h have degree 0. I compute the Euler char. of both and for g-1>0 it musn't be a covering (because there no exists an integer d such that 2-2g=d(2-2h)). So if I can demostrate the first question above for this special case this result about torus hold it.